# How can you access an object from a different class into one class in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, attributes, python-3.8

How can I access an object from a different class into another class?

```py
class Hello:
     def say_hello (self):
          print("Hello!")

class Robot:
     def hello (self):
          a = Hello()
          a.say_hello()
```

For example, in the following code, I have a "Hello" and "Robot" class. I want the Robot to say "hello" by taking the "say_hello" method from the "Hello" class. In this particular code, it works.
However, for more complicated code, will the same thing work?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: This was a basic code, I was making sure if it would work for more advanced codes. I edited my question. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: I don't think we'd be able to say without more context. "However, for more complicated code, will the same thing work?": that would depend on exactly what you're trying to do in the more complicated code.

Comment: @Carcigenicate is right, but as a general rule this is how you'd call a method from another class. It seems like class methods would be better suited to what you're doing though (the methods you've defined are called instance methods).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
class Hello:
 def say_hello (self):
      print("Hello!")

class Robot:
 def hello (self):
      a = Hello()
      a.say_hello()
 y = Robot()
 y.hello()
```

Works as attended.

Comment: Thank you. Just to clarify, this will work for any class, right?

Comment: If you want to do this for different classes i'd suggest abstract classes.